# Core Data - NSPredicate for objects with identical column and also meet another condition

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I am looking for a predicate to fetch all managed objects of type `Entity` whose values are duplicated in a property `sessionId`, where all groups' ("groups", meaning managed objects whose `sessionId`'s are equal) contents' flags in a property `processed` is set to YES. This can be done (slowly), but I am looking for an efficient one liner for this. Thanks

This is the slow way:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSArray *all = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
NSArray *sessionIds = [all valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.sessionId"];
NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *sessionId in sessionIds) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sessionId == %@", sessionId];
    NSArray *inSession = [all filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    for(id obj in inSession) {
         if(![obj valueForKey:@"processed"]) continue;
    }

    [objects arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:processed];
}
NSLog(@"%@", objects);
```

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: It's an open ended question--not a "please fix my code"

Comment: @Skyler - Maybe you should take Cliff's advice.  At least show the "slow" way because your description is confusing and unclear.  What do you mean by "whose values are duplicated in a column?"  What is "where all groups' contents' flags in column processed" supposed to mean?  Also, maybe you used the wrong terminology in your comment, but open-ended questions are inappropriate for stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @Jody added sample code

Comment: "Open Ended" questions are not what we want to see here.

Comment: How "slow" is your method? How did you measure it?

Comment: Your slow way doesn't work. The first statement can't be right and the predicate "ALL processed = YES" can't work.

Comment: @Willeke Fixed sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since booleans are stored as 0s and 1s, a group where all rows have `processed = YES` will have `average(processed) = 1`.  Hence you can use `NSFetchRequest`'s `propertiesToGroupBy` and `havingPredicate` to get the `sessionId`s that meet your criteria.  A second fetch is then required to get the `Entity` objects with any of those `sessionId`s:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
fetch.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetch.propertiesToFetch = @[@"sessionId"];
fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"sessionId"];
fetch.havingPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"average:(processed) == 1"];
NSArray *resultsArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
NSArray *sessionIdArray = [resultsArray valueForKeyPath:@"sessionId"];
NSFetchRequest *newFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
newFetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name IN %@",sessionIdArray];
NSArray *finalResults = [context executeFetchRequest:newFetch error:nil];
NSLog(@"Final results, %@", finalResults);
```

Sorry it's not a one-liner.  And I leave it to you to determine whether it's any quicker than your own code.

**EDIT**

To do it all in one fetch, use `NSFetchRequestExpression` in place of the intermediate arrays:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
fetch.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetch.propertiesToFetch = @[@"sessionId"];
fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"sessionId"];
fetch.havingPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"average:(processed) == 1"];
NSExpression *fetchExpression = [NSFetchRequestExpression expressionForFetch:[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:fetch] context:[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:context] countOnly:false];
NSFetchRequest *newFetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
newFetch.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sessionId IN %@",fetchExpression];
NSArray *finalResults = [context executeFetchRequest:newFetch error:nil];
NSLog(@"Final results, %@", finalResults);
```

Note that on my (admittedly trivial) test setup this actually ran more slowly than the two-fetch solution.

FYI, if you use the SQLDebug build setting to examine the SQL that is generated, it looks something like this:

> SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZSESSIONID, t0.ZPROCESSED FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZSESSIONID IN (SELECT n1_t0.ZSESSIONID FROM ZENTITY n1_t0 GROUP BY n1_t0.ZSESSIONID HAVING avg( n1_t0.ZPROCESSED) = ? )

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can this be done in a single fetch instead of two? I'd like to distribute as much of the computation into the SQLite level as possible rather than the CocoaTouch layer

Comment: Funny you should ask - I discovered how only a couple of days ago whilst researching another question.  I'll update my answer.